# Display in RViz the collision geometry tag of an URDF link

Tags: rviz, urdf, ros-melodic, collision, newtags

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to display in RViz the collision geometry tag (box, sphere, cylinder etc.) of an URDF link tag?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329752/display-in-rviz-the-collision-geometry-tag-of-an-urdf-link/) by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2019-07-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, if you add a RobotModel display in rviz and expand its options in the Displays panel, you should see a checkbox for "Collision Enabled". If you check it, you can see the collision models for your robot that were read from the URDF. A nice example of that can be found [here](http://sdk.rethinkrobotics.com/wiki/a/images/1/1d/Collision_model.png).

---

Originally posted by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) with karma: 642 on 2019-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1